# Close one modal ViewController and open another in same method. Possible?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

I have a situation where I want to open one modal controller from the other. But when the user closes either, they should go back to the parent controller of both modal controllers.

So I have the parent controller in charge of this. The method on the parent does something similar to the code below when the user clicks a button on the first modal controller.

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewController:YES];
SecondModalViewController *c = [[SecondModalViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:c animated:YES];
[c release];
```

The only thing that happens is the first view closes, but I don't see the second view open. Is it possible to close a modal ViewController and open a second one in the same method? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do that same thing all the time without a problem, though mine have `animated:NO`... I'm guessing your issue is because you have `animated:YES` on both. What effect are you looking for exactly? Do you want to see one get animated away, and then the other get animated in? If so, you need to execute the presentModalViewController with a delay.

Otherwise, you should just be able to present the second modal view controller without closing the first one at all. When you call dismissModalViewController; it should dismiss both.

Comment: I found the culprit: dismissing the first with animated:YES was preventing the second from opening. I tried to just open the second and not close the first, but that didn't work for me; that might be specific to my situation though.

Answer (score 7):

i think that by the time you close the first view controller, the [self.navigation presentmodal..] dosen't have a self to open the new one from.

you could do that:

use a boolean variable to state whether the **next time** this controller appears (when you close the one you're currently trying to open), it should close, and implements that feature in the viewDidApper: method, like so:

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController 
{
    //...
    BOOL close;
}
```

and in the .m file,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(close)
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    else
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
```

now, to open your new controller, do that:

```
-(IBAction)openSecondController:(id)sender{
    //..
    SecondViewController* controller = [[SecondViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    close = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
}
```

now, when you close the second one, the first one will close also. doesn't have any visible side affects in my apps..

not the cleanest way, but i didn't find a better one.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm finding exactly the same response. It looks like standard behaviour.

The way I got around it is to use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(presentController:) withObject:navController afterDelay:0.5f];
```

The only drawback was I had to set a presentController function which then did the presentModalViewController:animated:

I tried to use a NSInvocation but I kept on getting a bad access error when I tried to pass a BOOL for the animated argument.

The main thing is it works and my client is happy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use handle uiviewcontroller closed and open another with using Unwind Segues.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html